# Java and Silverlight together forever

Tags: java, silverlight

I want to display a silverlight web page inside my java desktop application.

Does anyone know of a plugin or browser control that I can use to do this?

Comment: together in perfect harmony? (in)side by side on the desktop?

Comment: You could do that, but I'm pretty sure this will result in a technical problem known as a clusterf***. For the love of whoever has to maintain your code, find another way.

Comment: No this is a collaboration with another company.  We need to work together so we can have synergy!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Embed an appropriate browser window into the Java app and it can load the SL - there will not be any interaction / communication between the two without some hacky code. Multiple browsers support SL but you are better off using the an IE based one at present, the chrome support is not official as I remember.

Answer (score 1):

How about an iFrame? In the nutshell... Alternatively you can make a request to .Net app from within your java server code using something like [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client/index.html) and then serve markup that way - would be relatively easy thing to do (relatively since if there authentication involved things can get complicated fast. And if you want (willing) to get "sophisticated" and you are using portlet technology there is [WSRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Services_for_Remote_Portlets)

For the desktop app I would go with [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client/index.html) suggestion: get the content, parse it then do with it what you please unless that Silverlite app is also running as webservice then you have some additional options by utilizing components that can consume services

Comment: Then use HttpClient to get the content and do whatever you need with it

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse's SWT provides out of the box web browser component based on IE and/or Mozilla engine. For swing application you can use one of ActiveX bridges, such as [J-Integra](http://j-integra.intrinsyc.com/support/com/doc/ocx/Internet_Explorer_OCX.html) or [JDIC](http://pcquest.ciol.com/content/coding/2004/104090202.asp) or [EZ JCOM](http://www.ezjcom.com/iexplore.html).

Answer (score 0):

Use [JDIC](https://jdic.dev.java.net/) WebBrowser component